# Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'

Tags: android, windows, react-native, build.gradle

when I run react-native run-android on my windows10 these errors appear. I was able to run this app before and it used to work just fine. I've been digging the internet for a solution for a few days now but I wasn't able to fix it. can anyone help me please? I would be really appreciated.
my system specifications:
windows 10
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.57.1 (I also tested 0.57.2 & 0.55.4)
babel: 4.6.1
gradle: 4.9
...............................error:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Could not determine the dependencies of task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.

  > Could not resolve all task dependencies for configuration ':app:debugCompileClasspath'.
  >   Could not resolve project :react-native-bluetooth-serial.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-bluetooth-serial: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.
  >   Could not resolve project :react-native-ble-plx.
  >    Required by:
  >        project :app
  >   Unable to find a matching configuration of project :react-native-ble-plx: None of the consumable configurations have attributes.

Comment: have you tried cleaning the cache? Using Powershell, navigate in the Android project folder and run `.\gradlew clean`

Comment: I think you haven't configured react-native-bluetooth-serial properly, you should verify code by following manual step for integration in that package.